# Getting access violation 0xc0000005 when updating QTextEdit

Tags: python, python-multithreading, pyside6

I am scraping some data on the internet using selenium, I needed my Pyside6 app to get updated, so I have this code to update a QTextEdit:

```
def log_out(self, MSG, TYPE):
    text = self.view.console.toPlainText()
    if TYPE == "Important":
        self.view.console.setText(text + "\n" + "                                          " + MSG)
    else:
        self.view.console.setText(text + "\n" + MSG)
```

I ran this code before entering a thread, and it worked just fine, but when I try to update it from inside the thread, it throughs this error and closes the app window without anything else. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: your code seems like it would cause a syntax error.  THere is no close quote or close parenthesis on line 4

Comment: there is, its just spaces, if you go to the right you will find ot @Alexander

Comment: Is QTextEdit supposed to be threadsafe?  I haven't used Pyside for a long time but it didn't used to be.  The GUI libraries I have worked with, widgets are typically not threadsafe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help @PaulCornelius and @Alexander, I found that the problem was actually that I was updating my QTextEdit two times consecutively. I don't know why would that be a problem, but when I removed one of the two, it worked.

Comment: No. The problem is that you can *never*, ***EVER*** access widgets directly from external threads. The **only** safe and proper way to update the GUI from there is by using QThreads and signals. Any other attempt is doomed to fail and crash sooner or later.

Comment: can you direct me to how to use QThreads, as I tried them before and it was really difficult to achieve and it didn't work as I wanted at the end, so if you have any good tutorials I would appreciate it @musicamante